# Como obter o formato em horas quando esta ultrapassa 24?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP onde preciso em algum momento obter o tempo total de um arquivo de áudio. Esse tempo é salvo no banco de dados em segundos e também no formato de horas.

O problema é que, quando formato essas horas através dos segundos salvos no banco, isso funciona normalmente, porém apenas se o arquivo tiver o tempo menor que 24 horas.

Exemplo:

```
$date = new DateTime('@0'); // "zeramos" a data

$tempo_1 =  10 * 3600; // 10 horas

$tempo_2 = 18 * 3600; // 18 horas

$tempo_3 = 28 * 3600; // 28 horas


echo $date->setTime(0, 0, $tempo_1)->format('H:i:s'); // 10:00:00

echo $date->setTime(0, 0, $tempo_2)->format('H:i:s'); // 18:00:00

echo $date->setTime(0, 0, $tempo_3)->format('H:i:s'); // 04:00:00
```

No último exemplo, o resultado desejado era `28:00:00`. Porém, como se trata de uma classe que trabalha com datas, é retornado `04:00:00`, por conta de `24` equivaler a 1 dia.

Como eu poderia fazer para obter esse tempo formatado em horas, mesmo que esta ultrapasse 24 horas?

Comment: `$tempo_1` é UNIX time?

Comment: Posso não ter entendido ou posso estar falando besteira mas o que você quer não parece ser possível. O tipo `DateTime` espera um horário válido (sei lá, o PHP pode ter subvertido isto mas em linguagens decentes é assim q funciona), então 28:00:00 não é um horário possível neste tipo.

Comment: Concordo com você @bigown. A classe é feita para trabalhar com Datas, e não com tempo em si. Há alguma maneira (ou uma gambiarra) que possa ser feita para resolver meu problema? estou usando uma função com um `sprintf`, mas me sinto desconfortável com ela (além do quê, ela está "roubando" 1 segundo do arquivo do áudio)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, fiz um pequeno ajuste na instância de `DateTime`. `$tempo_1` na verdade seria a duração em segundos do áudio. No caso, quero que, se ele tiver `100800` (que são 28 horas), eu o converta para o formato `28:00:00`. Porém, ele exibe `04:00:00`, pois ele cria `1 dia` ao invés das `24 horas` existentes dentro das `28 horas`;

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, meu valor não é exatamente em `unix time`. Porém a classe trabalha com `unix time` (espero não ter falado bobagem)

Comment: porque date? se esta tratando só de tempo não seria melhor trabalhar só com Time? Usando só o time você não teria esse problema de datas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não recomendo, mas dá para fazer uma gambiarra:

```
function dtLength($sec) {
    $t=new DateTime("@".$sec);
    $r=new DateTime("@0");
    $i=$t->diff($r);
    $h=intval($i->format("%a"))*24+intval($i->format("%H"));
    return $h.":".$i->format("%I:%S");
}

$date = new DateTime;
$tempo_1 =  10 * 3600; // 10 horas
$tempo_2 = 18 * 3600; // 18 horas
$tempo_3 = 28 * 3600; // 28 horas
echo $date->setTime(0, 0, $tempo_1)->format('H:i:s'); // 10:00:00
echo $date->setTime(0, 0, $tempo_2)->format('H:i:s'); // 18:00:00
echo $date->setTime(0, 0, $tempo_3)->format('H:i:s'); // 04:00:00
echo dtLength($tempo_1);
echo dtLength($tempo_2);
echo dtLength($tempo_3);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/2N5dHz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FormatTime). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/FormatTime.php).

Função retirada [dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13561224/221800).

Outra possibilidade é trabalhar com [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/DateInterval). Este tipo mostra tempos, que é o que parece estar querendo usar, ao invés de horas. Provavelmente é mais apropriado para o que você quer.

Comment: Meu pai amado! não queria ter que li dar com esse tipo de coisa. O projeto está no Laravel, e está tão bonitinho!

Comment: Uai, não estou entendendo vocês dois! O problema é usar uma classe de datas pra representar algo que não é uma data. Por que o drama, por que "não recomendo" e por que "meu pai amado"?! Se não está lidando com datas, não use a classe de datas, ou se vire com uma gambiarra! É simples, nem tudo pode ser sempre bonitinho :)

Comment: Acho que vou dar uma olhada no `DateInterval`, sabe, @bfavaretto?!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Boa ideia, bem capaz que funcione!

Comment: Qualquer coisa, eu dou um `sprintf` no código, onde está concatenado, para sentir pelo menos um pouquinho de "sensação de organização". ;) ;) ;)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Se encontrar outra solução que não seja a gambiarra acima, poste depois como resposta.

Comment: Não sei se vou achar. Foi o melhor que encontrei até agora. A não ser que façamos uma classe só pra isso e colocamos ela no Github :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters provavelmente esta classe já existe e ela se chama `DateInterval`.

Comment: DateTime é uma coisa que quanto mais você tira do código PHP, mais limpo ele fica.

Answer (score 12):

As soluções apresentadas anteriormente são muito boas.

Porém, mesmo que pareça estupido, acabei descobrindo uma outra solução para esse problema  utilizando a função `SEC_TO_TIME` do `Mysql`.

Veja:

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( 28 * 3600 )
--28:00:00
```

Então, que fique registrado, caso alguém tenha um problema parecido com esse!

Parece que nesse ponto, o `Mysql` simplificou as coisas muito mais do que o próprio PHP.

## Atualização

Desenvolvi uma biblioteca para podermos trabalhar com os tempos de maneira mais precisa. E utilizei algumas das soluções aqui aplicadas no código fonte.

Se interessarem:

https://github.com/wallacemaxters/timer

Comment: Nossa não me parece estupido a "descoberta", me parece que você simplificou a vida de muitas pessoas. Grande resposta! Só um detalhe eu adicionei a tag mysql, porque se não a resposta não teria muito sentido.

Comment: Obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento. A ideia me surgiu a cabeça depois que já tinha sido feito a pergunta e também dada a resposta. Obrigado pela correção.

Comment: Notei que no seu repositório você usou o `floor`, então acredito que você conseguiu encontrar o problema do -1 segundo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, descobri o porquê. Os segundos são salvos como `float`!. Ou seja, `24.4` uma hora poderá dar pau!

Comment: Então mas ao meu ver a soma teria que ser com o unixtime, só acho

Comment: Talvez eu tenha que usar o `ceil` no meus dados `float`, e não dentro da função, entende?

Comment: Bom dia, entendi @WallaceMaxters , este problema é fora da função, mas está vindo float do banco de dados?

Comment: É fora da função. Seu código está certo :)

Comment: A sim, legal, só queria saber como você chegou ao `float` (fora da função).

Answer (score 12):

> **Nota:** No caso o autor resolveu usando MySql, então está resposta pode para acaso dados que venham de uma outra "fonte" aonde não tenha um recurso semelhante ao `SEC_TO_TIME`.

Se o formato do tempo é em segundos você pode calcular usando o PHP sem a necessidade de classes "avançadas" para isto, como o exemplo [desta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856312/1518921)

Apenas fiz um ajuste para que numeros quebrados sejam suportados, usando a função [**`fmod()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)

O código ficou assim:

```
<?php
function getFullHour($seconds) {
    $negative = $seconds < 0; //Verifica se é um valor negativo

    if ($negative) {
        $seconds = -$seconds; //Converte o negativo para positivo para poder fazer os calculos
    }

    $hours = $seconds / 3600;

    $mins = ($seconds - ($hours * 3600)) / 60;

    //Pega o valor após o ponto flutuante
    $f = fmod($hours, 1);

    //Adiciona minutos se $seconds for quebrado
    if ($f > 0) $mins += 60 * $f;

    $secs = $seconds % 60;

    $sign = $negative ? '-' : ''; //Adiciona o sinal de negativo se necessário

    return $sign . sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
}

echo getFullHour(3.002 * 60 * 60), PHP_EOL; //03:00:07
echo getFullHour(3.5 * 60 * 60), PHP_EOL; //03:30:00

echo getFullHour(3 * 60 * 60), PHP_EOL; //03:00:00

echo getFullHour(140801), PHP_EOL; //39:06:41
echo getFullHour(100800), PHP_EOL; //28:00:00

echo getFullHour(-140801), PHP_EOL; //-39:06:41
echo getFullHour(-100800), PHP_EOL; //-28:00:00
```

Teste online no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/@inphinit/hours-greater-than-24-php)

Comment: O que o `str_pad` faz exatamente nessa concatenação? E outra coisa: porque se usa `floor`, e não `ceil`? Tive problemas com o "arredondamento para baixo", pois o áudio ficava com 1 segundo a menos.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, @GuilhermeNascimento. Eu entendi que você usava o str_pad para preencher os números com zero, mas não há necessidade de usá-los. A função `sprintf` faz isso. E eu acho uma boa idéia retornar `false` caso o valor do argumento não seja o esperado. Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/9bMIT4) a pequena refatoração que eu fiz. http://ideone.com/9bMIT4

Comment: Obrigado pela dica do `sprintf` (sempre me esqueço e vou pelo mais dificil), no questão de retornar false eu preferi usar `NULL`. O `floor` retornou -1 segundos? Poderia fornecer um exemplo?

Comment: Na verdade, @GuilhermeNascimento, é o seguinte: Eu utilizo a biblioteca `GETID3` para obter o tempo do áudio. Aí, eu salvo o tempo em segundos e o tempo formatado, que ele gera. Aí, quando tenho que somar esses tempos, tenho que usar os segundos para somar os tempos dos áudios e formatar. Aí se eu tenho dois áudios com `3:00:02`  e `3:00:00`, ao invés de retornar `6:00:2`, ele retorna `6:00:1`. Para mim não faz diferença, mas para meu cliente faz, e muita!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21411/discussion-between-wallace-maxters-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro precisamos entender dois conceitos importantes. Considere as duas frases abaixo:

- o filme será exibido às duas horas da manhã
- o filme tem duas horas de duração

No primeiro caso, "duas horas" refere-se ao **horário** (um momento específico do dia). Tudo bem que ele precisa de "da manhã" para não ser ambíguo (poderia ser 2 da tarde), mas o fato é que está se referindo a um momento específico.

No segundo caso, "duas horas" refere-se à **duração** (uma quantidade de tempo). Não é dito que horas o filme começa, e nem se vai passar ou já passou. É somente a quantidade de tempo, sem qualquer relação com horários.

Esses dois conceitos **não são a mesma coisa**. Datas e horários referem-se a pontos na linha do tempo: uma data (dia, mês e ano) refere-se a um ponto específico de um calendário, e um horário (hora, minuto, segundo, frações de segundo) refere-se a um momento específico de um dia. Durações são apenas quantidades de tempo, que existem por si só, sem estarem atrelados a uma data e hora específicas.

O que confunde é o fato de que ambos (tanto horários quanto durações) usam exatamente as mesmas palavras (dias, horas, minutos, etc), e muitas vezes são escritos da mesma maneira (um relógio mostra "02:00:00" quando é duas da manhã, um cronômetro mostra "02:00:00" quando a contagem do tempo atinge duas horas).

Outro ponto que pode - erroneamente - nos fazer pensar que horários e durações são a mesma coisa é que, embora sejam conceitos diferentes, eles podem estar relacionados. Se eu calcular a diferença entre duas datas, o resultado é uma duração (sabendo a data/hora que começou e que terminou, consigo calcular quanto tempo durou), e se eu somar uma data/hora com uma duração, o resultado é outra data/hora (sabendo a data/hora que começou e quanto tempo durou, consigo calcular a data/hora que terminou).

---

Dito isso, um [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) serve para trabalhar com datas e horas (pontos na linha do tempo), mas não com durações.

Para trabalhar com durações, você pode usar um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php). Com ele você pode criar uma instância que corresponde a uma determinada quantidade de tempo, e formatá-la através do [método `format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php). Ex:

```
$tempo_1 = new DateInterval('PT10H'); // duração de 10 horas
$tempo_2 = new DateInterval('PT18H'); // duração de 18 horas
$tempo_3 = new DateInterval('PT28H'); // duração de 28 horas

$formato = '%H:%I:%S';
echo $tempo_1->format($formato); // 10:00:00
echo $tempo_2->format($formato); // 18:00:00
echo $tempo_3->format($formato); // 28:00:00
```

Repare que o formato usado é diferente do que é usado no [método `format` de um `DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). Para um `DateInterval`, além das letras precisarem ter o `%` antes, algumas são diferentes (por exemplo, para formatar o `DateTime`, usa-se o `i` minúsculo para os minutos e o `s` minúsculo para os segundos, mas para um `DateInterval` deve-se usar `I` e `S` maiúsculos para que eles tenham o zero à esquerda para valores menores que 10).

Outro detalhe é que o construtor de `DateInterval` recebe uma [duração no formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). Basicamente, o `P` no início é obrigatório (vem do inglês "Period", outro nome para "quantidade de tempo"). O `T` serve para indicar que os campos a seguir referem-se a horas, minutos e segundos (pois antes do `T` podemos ter campos referentes a dias, meses e anos - por exemplo, `P2Y3MT10H5M` é uma duração de 2 anos, 3 meses, 10 horas e 5 minutos).

---

No caso de ter somente a quantidade total de segundos, não adiantaria fazer `new DateInterval("PT{$segundos}S")`, já que esta classe não transforma a quantidade total de segundos em horas, minutos e segundos (`PT120S` - 120 segundos - é formatado como `00:00:120`, e não como `00:02:00`). Nesse caso, você teria que calcular manualmente as horas, minutos e segundos (como sugerido na [resposta do Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51828/112052)) e em seguida criar o `DateInterval`. Ex:

```
$seconds = 100800;
// calcular manualmente as horas, minutos e segundos (versão simplificada da resposta do Guilherme Nascimento)
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
$secs = floor($seconds % 60);

$tempo_1 = new DateInterval("PT{$hours}H{$mins}M{$secs}S");
echo $tempo_1->format('%H:%I:%S'); // 28:00:00
```

Se bem que nesse caso, parece um exagero usar `DateInterval`, pois você já calculou cada campo separadamente e bastaria imprimi-los.

A documentação ainda sugere outras alternativas para transformar 100800 segundos em 28 horas, como [esta](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#113204) (que usa uma lógica parecida com a [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51822/112052), de usar um `DateTime` para obter outro `DateInterval`), ou [essa](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php#102271) (que faz os cálculos similares à [resposta do Guilherme Nascimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51828/112052)). Infelizmente, `DateInterval` não faz esta conversão nativamente.