# Calcular horas em PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, aplicação-web, data, time

Estou desenvolvendo um ponto eletrônico em PHP e gostaria de saber como fazer o Caculo de duas horas sendo que uma delas é negativa, por exemplo:

Carga horária dia 1: -05:00:00

Carga horária dia 2: 08:00:00

Como faria a conta das duas horas para obter o saldo de horas?

Comment: Horas negativas? Como isto funciona, seriam horas que o usuário deve, tipo ele não foi trabalhar? Não seria melhor só calcular as horas acessadas e deduzir das horas semanais por exemplo?

Comment: Boa tarde, a resposta resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um código adaptado dessa [resposta](http://www.codingforums.com/php/150266-sum-times-post739893.html?s=935266d07178affa5c552c13181ba908#post739893):

```
$horas = array(
    '-05:00:00',
    '08:00:00'
);

$seconds = 0;

foreach ( $horas as $hora )
{
    list( $g, $i, $s ) = explode( ':', $hora );
    if ($g < 0) {
        $i *= -1;
        $s *= -1;
    }
    $seconds += $g * 3600;
    $seconds += $i * 60;
    $seconds += $s;
}

$hours    = floor( $seconds / 3600 );
$seconds -= $hours * 3600;
$minutes  = floor( $seconds / 60 );
$seconds -= $minutes * 60;

echo "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
```

**Saída**:

> 3:0:0

### [IdeOne Exemplo](http://ideone.com/m1yUHD)

Answer (score 1):

Eu não entendi bem o uso das horas negativas, ao meu ver seria melhor ter o numero de horas que você teve acesso e deduzir das horas diárias, semanais ou mensais.

*Parece* que está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22922030/1518921) resolve o seu problema

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '11:30:00');
$start->add(new DateInterval('PT8H30M'));
$end   = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '19:30:00');
$diff = $start->diff($end);
echo $diff->format('%r%H:%I');
```

Eu não testei, mas ao que parece você adiciona 8 horas e meia e deduz do resultado final.

No entanto se quiser algo mais simples, você pode usar o unix-time, algo como (usando a função desta resposta [Como obter o formato em horas quando esta ultrapassa 24?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51828/3635)):

```
//Transforma as horas em "inteiro"
function toUnixTime($total) {
    $negativo = false;
    if (strpos($total, '-') === 0) {
        $negativo = true;
        $total = str_replace('-', '', $total);
    }

    list($horas, $minutos, $segundos) = explode(':', $total);
    $ut = mktime($horas, $minutos, $segundos);
    if ($negativo) {
        return -$ut;
    }

    return $ut;
}

//Gera horarios acima de 24 horas (para calculo total)
function getFullHour($input) {
    $seconds = intval($input);
    $resp = NULL;//Em caso de receber um valor não suportado retorna nulo

    if (is_int($seconds)) {
        $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
        $mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
        $secs = floor($seconds % 60);

        $resp = sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
    }

    return $resp;
}

$dia1 = toUnixTime('-05:00:00');
$dia2 = toUnixTime('08:00:00');

//Compara os dois horarios
$calculo = $dia1 + $dia2;

echo getFullHour($calculo);
```