# Como converter segundos para o formato "Hora:Minuto:Segundo"?

Tags: php, time

Como posso converter um valor em segundos para um formato de 'horas:minutos:segundos'.

Exemplo: **685** convertido à **00:11:25**

Como consigo fazer?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pode ir dividindo os segundos para achar as horas e minutos:

```
$total = 685;
$horas = floor($total / 3600);
$minutos = floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
$segundos = floor($total % 60);
echo $horas . ":" . $minutos . ":" . $segundos;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5XiLMP). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hdnunook-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/ConversionTIme.php).

Comment: Esse código retorna `0:11:25` e não `00:11:25` conforme pretendido pelo AP

Answer (score 19):

Pode usar a função [`gmdate()`](https://www.php.net/gmdate):

```
echo gmdate("H:i:s", 685);
```

<sub>Se refere a [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172358/1245766) do SOen</sub>

Comment: Estava querendo colocar de wiki, mas não estou conseguindo fazê-lo.

Comment: Falo a resposta, e a pergunta também.

Comment: Acho a pergunta válida e útil. Não vejo necessidade de ser convertida em wiki

Answer (score 5):

Além do calculo, já passado pelo [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75993/3635):

```
$horas = floor($total / 3600);
$minutos = floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
$segundos = floor($total % 60);
```

É importante lembrar que se um dos números for menor que 10, então pode sair um formato assim:

```
1:4:31
```

Quando o esperado deveria ser:

```
01:04:31
```

Para isto pode usar `str_pad` ou `sprintf` (este ultimo sugestão do [Wallace](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters)), como sugeri em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51828/3635:

```
<?php
function getFullHour($input) {
    $seconds = intval($input); //Converte para inteiro

    $negative = $seconds < 0; //Verifica se é um valor negativo

    if ($negative) {
        $seconds = -$seconds; //Converte o negativo para positivo para poder fazer os calculos
    }

    $hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
    $mins = floor(($seconds - ($hours * 3600)) / 60);
    $secs = floor($seconds % 60);

    $sign = $negative ? '-' : ''; //Adiciona o sinal de negativo se necessário

    return $sign . sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $mins, $secs);
}

echo getFullHour(685), PHP_EOL; //00:11:25

echo getFullHour(140801), PHP_EOL; //39:06:41
echo getFullHour(100800), PHP_EOL; //28:00:00

echo getFullHour(-140801), PHP_EOL; //-39:06:41
echo getFullHour(-100800), PHP_EOL; //-28:00:00
```

Veja um exemplo no repl.it: https://repl.it/@inphinit/Show-hours-over-24-hours-and-negative-hours

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float time, hour, min, sec;
    scanf("%f", &time);
    hour = time / 3600;
    min = (((time/3600) - (int)hour) * 3600)/60;
    sec = (min - (int)min) * 60; 
    printf("%.0f\n%.0f\n%.0f\n", hour, min, sec);
    return 0;
    
}
```