# Transformar Sequência de Números em Data com PHP e SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tenho um banco de dados que tem uma sequência numérica gravada em uma tabela que significa uma data de publicação de um artigo. Gostaria de saber se alguém consegue decifrar esta sequência numérica para que eu consiga imprimir a data correta através do PHP.

**Por exemplo:**

```
1464880280 = 02/06/2016
1465580280 = 10/06/2016
1466513100 = 21/06/2016
```

Alguém consegue decifrar e me ajudar a criar uma função para exibir esta data convertida?

Comment: Parece duplicata de: [Como converter segundos para o formato “Hora:Minuto:Segundo”?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75991/91)

Answer (score 5):

Esta sequência numérica é a data em formato UNIX Timestamp. Já existe função para conversão.

Exemplo em php:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', 1464880280);
echo date('d/m/Y', 1465580280);
echo date('d/m/Y', 1466513100);
```

Para mais informações [acesse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 3):

Você também pode formatar no MySQL utilizando [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) e [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

Exemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1464880280),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') as dt;
```