# Converter formato hora em segundos

Tags: php, json

Tenho um valor exibido por um json:

```
"tempoShoutcast":"03:11:48"
```

Como posso transformar esse formato para segundos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Usando função pronta

Considerando que o `strtotime` do PHP usa Posix/Unix time, um jeito bem simples é esse:

```
$horario = "03:11:48";
$segundos = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$horario.'UTC');
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/HR7uth)**.

Isto funciona, pois o Posix Time é o número de segundos desde primeiro de janeiro de 1970, portanto, o horário desse dia é exatamente o número de segundos que você busca.

### Usando cálculo

Se quiser fazer o cálculo "manualmente", pode ser assim:

```
$horario = "03:11:48";
$partes = explode(':', $horario);
$segundos = $partes[0] * 3600 + $partes[1] * 60 + $partes[2];
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/j7ya1a)**.

Simplesmente estamos dividindo o horário em partes, multiplicando a hora por 3600 (que é 60 minutos * 60 segundos ), os minutos por 60, e finalmente somando os segundos restantes.

Para fazer o inverso, veja aqui:

> [Como converter segundos para o formato "Hora:Minuto:Segundo"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75990/70)

Answer (score -1):

E bem simples so você usar

```
$segundos = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$horario.'UTC');
```

e pronto, tá feito.

Comment: Bom, só para deixar claro, eu negativei por ser uma cópia exata da minha solução, ou seja, esta resposta aqui não é útil (que é uma das razões descritas no próprio indicador de downvote)