# Como verificar o tempo de um video

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de ajuda em um problema. Preciso verificar o tempo total de um video incorporado em um site e o tempo de video que foi assistido. Alguém teria poderia me da um norte a ser tomado? Obrigado!

Answer (score 5):

Em JavaScript use as propriedades:

- `.currentTime`: posição em segundos do vídeo
- `.duration`: tempo em segundos total do vídeo

> **Nota:** não é possivel pegar a posição atual do video via PHP, PHP esta do lado do servidor e não do lado do cliente, o que você pode fazer é enviar `currentTime` via um formulário ou via Ajax

Então com `document.querySelector` pode pegar o video, um exemplo:

```js
var meuVideo = document.querySelector('#meuVideo');
var pegarBtn = document.querySelector('#pegarBtn');
var playBtn = document.querySelector('#playBtn');

pegarBtn.onclick = function () {
    console.log("posição atual:", meuVideo.currentTime);
    console.log("duração:", meuVideo.duration);
};

playBtn.onclick = function () {
    meuVideo.play();
};
```

```html
<button id="playBtn">Iniciar video</button>
<button id="pegarBtn">Pegar tempo</button>

<video id="meuVideo" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
```

### Formatando o tempo

Para converter os segundos para uma formato mais fácil visualmente de entender você pode dividir de 60 em 60, por exemplo (exemplo do [Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/75993/3635) em PHP):

```js
var tempo = 1909202;

var horas = Math.floor(tempo / 3600);
var minutos = Math.floor((tempo - (horas * 3600)) / 60);
var segundos = Math.floor(tempo % 60);

if (horas < 10) horas = '0' + horas;
if (minutos < 10) minutos = '0' + minutos;
if (segundos < 10) segundos = '0' + segundos;

console.log(horas + ':' + minutos + ':' + segundos);
```

Então no seu video poderia usar assim:

```js
function humanizar_horas(tempo)
{
    var horas = Math.floor(tempo / 3600);
    var minutos = Math.floor((tempo - (horas * 3600)) / 60);
    var segundos = Math.floor(tempo % 60);

    if (horas < 10) horas = '0' + horas;
    if (minutos < 10) minutos = '0' + minutos;
    if (segundos < 10) segundos = '0' + segundos;

    return horas + ':' + minutos + ':' + segundos;
}

var meuVideo = document.querySelector('#meuVideo');
var pegarBtn = document.querySelector('#pegarBtn');
var playBtn = document.querySelector('#playBtn');

pegarBtn.onclick = function () {
    console.log("posição atual:", humanizar_horas(meuVideo.currentTime));
    console.log("duração:", humanizar_horas(meuVideo.duration));
};

playBtn.onclick = function () {
    meuVideo.play();
};
```

```html
<button id="playBtn">Iniciar video</button>
<button id="pegarBtn">Pegar tempo</button>

<video id="meuVideo" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
```

---

### Com PHP

Como eu já disse, como PHP diretamente não é possível pegar o tempo atual do video (até aonde assistiu), mas é possivel pegar a duração:

Você pode experimentar o `getID3`, baixe ele em https://sourceforge.net/projects/getid3/files/getID3%28%29%201.x/

```
require_once '<pasta aonde salvou o getid3>/getid3/getid3.php';

$filename = '<pasta aonde esta o video>/video.mp4';

$getID3 = new getID3;
$file = $getID3->analyze($filename);

echo 'Duração: ', $file['playtime_string'], PHP_EOL,
     'Resolução: ', $file['video']['resolution_x'], 'x', $file['video']['resolution_y'], PHP_EOL,
     'Bytes: ', $file['filesize'];
```

Ou instalar o **ffmpeg** e usar combinado com o `shell_exec()` do PHP, exemplo baseado nesta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/6251209/1518921:

```
function getDuration($path) {
     $response = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i ' . escapeshellarg($path) . ' 2>&1', $output);

     $parseduration = '/duration.*?([0-9]{1,})/';

     if (preg_match($parseduration, $response, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3) > 0) {
         return $matches[1][0];
     }
}

echo 'Duração: ', getDuration('pasta/video.flv');
```

Comment: Ela só funciona em <embed> e <video>?

Comment: @ErickAnderson só em `<video>` e `<audio>`. A tag `<embed>` esta obsoleta, use a tag video para videos e audio para musicas.

Comment: @ErickAnderson editei a resposta com um exemplo de como humanizar o tempo do video, deixando ele em um formato "00:00:00", assim fica mais fácil ler