# Começar vídeo de onde parou - resumir vídeo de onde parou - site

Tags: html5-video, reprodutor-de-video

Como faço para manter salvo o progresso atual de um vídeo, mesmo atualizando ou saindo da página?

O vídeo está ná pagina com este código simples:

< div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" >
  < iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="video.mp4" allowfullscreen>
< /div >

Comment: Salve o tempo do vídeo em um localStorage. Como acha o tempo do vídeo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289993/como-verificar-o-tempo-de-um-video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Solução:

```js
var temp = 0;
var vid = document.getElementById('myvideo');

vid.onloadstart = function() {
/* if ( typeof localStorage.get('temp') == 'number') {
  temp = localStorage.getItem('temp');
  vid.currentTime = temp;
}*/
setInterval(function() {
  temp = vid.currentTime;
  // localStorage.setItem('temp',temp);
}, 1000);
};
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <body>
    <video width="320" height="240" id='myvideo' controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
    <br>
    <button onclick='console.log(temp)'>Tempo</button>
  </body>

  </html>
```

O vídeo cada segundo vai atualiza o localStorage com tempo do vídeo, isso vai evitar travamentos.

**OBS**: Remova os // e o /* */

Fonte:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp