# Como aciono um evento js quando um vídeo html atingir um dado segundo?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, javascript-eventos, html5-video

Então, a situação é o seguinte:
Imagine um vídeo no html e imagine que esse vídeo tem 1 minuto.
Eu queria saber como posso fazer pra acionar um evento para quando o vídeo atingir a marca de 30 segundos.

Quem puder e souber responder, agradeço desde já :D

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 6):

Use o evento [`timeupdate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event) (que é suportado tanto por ambos `<video>` e `<audio>`) junto com a propriedade [`HTMLMediaElement.currentTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) (retorna o valor em segundos)

> Nota: Veja mais eventos e propriedades do em [**HTMLMediaElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)

Um exemplo simples seria:

```
<video id="meuvideo"></video>

var video = document.querySelector('#meuvideo');

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (event) {
  console.log(video.currentTime);
});
```

Nessa resposta forneço um exemplo de como obter a hora formatada:

- [Como verificar o tempo de um video](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289996/3635)

No entanto formatar a hora só para comparar é muito trabalho que pode ser resolvido tendo o valor "absoluto" já antes, imaginando que você quer que o evento dispare quando o vídeo estiver em `00:10` (dez segundos) então simplesmente poderia fazer:

```
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (event) {
    if (video.currentTime >= 10) {
       console.log('Dispare aqui a ação desejada');
    }
});
```

Se quiser que dispare exatamente no *décimo segundo* tenha em mente que o valor retornado pelo `currentTime` será quebrado, então dentro do `timeupdate` o `currentTime` pode retornar algo como `9.901458` no nono segundo e em seguida `10.026666` quando estiver no décimo segundo. Uma checagem assim `if (video.currentTime == 10)`  **não** funcionará, exemplo:

```js
var time = 10.026666; // Simulado

if (time == 10) {
  console.log('Dispara o evento');
} else {
  console.log('NÃO dispara o evento');
}
```

**Então** você pode adaptar a checagem para isso:

```js
var time = 10.026666; // Simulado

if (time >= 10 && time < 11) {
  console.log('Dispara o evento');
} else {
  console.log('NÃO dispara o evento');
}
```

Note que no mesmo segundo o `timeupdate` pode disparar mais de uma vez, nesse caso é bom criar uma checagem com uma variável `bool` para evitar que dispare duas vezes

```
var trigged = false;

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function (event) {
    var time = video.currentTime;

    if (!trigged && time >= 10 && time < 11) {
       trigged = true; // Impede de disparar mais de uma vez
       console.log('Dispare aqui a ação desejada');
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Existem duas maneiras de fazer isso, a mais convencional é usando:

```
videoElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', (event) => { 
   //e aqui você pode pegar o valor como event.target.currentTime 
}
```

Se você pretende fazer essa ação pro vídeo correndo normalmente essse trecho vai servir, porém se você pretende realizar a ação durante o seek do video(quando o usuário clica em determinado período do vídeo ou arrasta o indicador) pode se tornar problemático, uma vez que seu video pode não estar carregado, resultando na trava temporária da sua função de observação. Eu prefiro usar como:

```
    setInterval(async () => {
         let TempoAtual = videoElement.currentTime
         if(TempoAtual >= tempo que voce quer que atinja){
             //seu código aqui
         }
    },100);
```

Isso executa a verificação a cada 100ms, não importando se o player esta correndo normalmente ou se foi clicado//arrastado pelo usuário :)