# Transformar m:s em segundos

Tags: php

Como transformar um valor em segundos? Por exemplo: 01:32, no caso seria 92 segundos.

Gostaria de fazer isso em php, já procurei na net mas não encontro nada.

Comment: Se precisar do oposto => [Como converter segundos para o formato “Hora:Minuto:Segundo”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75990/91)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Uma opção seria usando o `explode`:

```
$tempo = "01:32";
$segundos = explode(":",$tempo);
$total = ((int)$segundos[0] * 60) + (int)$segundos[1];
echo $total;
```

Uma outra opção seria usando `strtotime`

```
$tempo = "00:01:32";
$total = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$tempo .'UTC');
echo $total;
```

Conforme elucidado pelo @bfavaretto, esta opção tem um limite de [89999 segundos](https://repl.it/repls/TerribleFrayedLearning) para que ela funcione corretamente. Ou seja, o valor limite para ser convertido de [24 horas, 59 minutos e 59 segundos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060467/difference-between-2400-and-0000/13060823#13060823).

Caso você tenha o parâmetro de hora na primeira opção, você pode usa-lo assim:

```
$tempo = "01:01:32";
$segundos = explode(":",$tempo);
$total = ((int)$segundos[0] * 60 * 60)+ ((int)$segundos[1] * 60) + (int)$segundos[2];
echo $total;
```

Comment: acredito que a segunda opção é correta pois a primeira se o valor for `01:01:32` deve retornar `61`

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim.. dependendo de como vem a variável ele terá que usar a segunda mesmo. É até melhor mesmo.

Comment: Interessante: a segunda versão [funciona para até 89999 segundos](https://repl.it/repls/TerribleFrayedLearning). Serve para representar horas de um dia (e o php por algum motivo estranho [entende até 24 horas, 59 minutos e 59 segundos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13060823/825789)). Mas não serve para representar uma duração com 25+ horas.

Comment: @bfavaretto seria bom colocar isso na resposta?

Comment: Pode ser. A pergunta não deixa claro qual é o uso que vai fazer (se ultrapassa um dia), então é sempre bom contemplar todas as possibilidades.

Answer (score 9):

```
$tempo_total= "4:44";

sscanf($tempo_total, "%d:%d:%d", $horas, $minutos, $segundos);

$tempo_segundos = isset($segundos) ? $horas * 3600 + $minutos * 60 + $segundos : $horas * 60 + $minutos;
```

[Rodando no ideone](https://ideone.com/fsvT9V)

Answer (score 6):

Não é a melhor solução (a melhor é do Daniel Gomes Da Silva), mas também serve para representar uma duração com 25+ horas além de botar em pratica algum conhecimento em PHP

```
 $tempo_total= "30:4:44";

 if (substr_count($tempo_total, ':')==2){
     $tempo_segundos = (int)$tempo_total*3600 + (int)(substr(strstr($tempo_total, ':'), 1))*60 + substr($tempo_total, -2);
 }else{
     $tempo_segundos = (int)$tempo_total*60 + substr($tempo_total, -2);
 }

 echo $tempo_segundos; //108284
```

[Com horas - ideone](https://ideone.com/UroJuD)

[Sem horas - ideone](https://ideone.com/bcpnLE)

1 - A conversão de string para inteiro depende do formato da string, assim o PHP avalia o formato da string e caso não possua nenhum valor numérico será convertido para 0(zero). **Caso possua valor numérico em sua primeira posição** o valor será considerado e caso o valor não seja na primeira posição será desconsiderado.  [exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/gnJ0di)

```
 $tempo_total= "30:4:44";
 $num = (int)$tempo_total;
 var_dump ($num); // int(30)
```

2 - `substr_count($tempo_total, ':')` conta o numero de ocorrências do caractere `:` (dois pontos) para aplicar à condicional, ***se igual a 2*** quer dizer que a variável `$tempo_total` é formada por horas, minutos e segundos e executa o `if` e caso contrário executa o `else`

3 - `strstr($tempo_total, ':')` - retorna parte da string `$tempo_total` a partir da primeira ocorrência de `:` até o final, neste caso retorna `:4:44`

4 - `substr(strstr($tempo_total, ':'), 1)` - retorna parte do retorno do item acima `:4:44` a partir da posição 1, ou seja `4:44`. Convertendo para inteiro (veja item 1) temos: [exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/j3CoKC)

```
 $num = (int)"4:44";
 var_dump ($num); // int(4)
```

5 - `substr($tempo_total, -2)` - um índice negativo, desta forma o PHP analisa a string contando N caracteres a partir do final