# Como transformar string em time no PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

Tenho 2 strings que representam horários. Como calcular a diferença entre as duas.

```
$string1 = "12:04:32";
$string2 = "18:07:34";
```

Comment: você pode usar o `diff->` caso use orientação a objeto.

Comment: Só para complementar as respostas, recomendo a leitura de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51821/como-obter-o-formato-em-horas-quando-esta-ultrapassa-24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o código abaixo:

```
<?php

$string1 = strtotime("12:04:32");
$string2 = strtotime("18:07:34");

$intervalo  = abs($string2 - $string1);
var_dump('Diferença em segundos: ' . $intervalo);

$minutos   = round($intervalo / 60, 2);
var_dump('Diferença em minutos: ' . $minutos);

$horas   = round($minutos / 60, 2);
var_dump('Diferença em horas: ' . $horas);

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar a combinação dos métodos `diff()` qual calcula a diferença entre as horas e [format()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) para formatar a hora conforme o desejado da classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

DateTime existe desde o PHP 5.2, já  os métodos [diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) e [createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) estão disponíveis apenas no PHP 5.3

```
<?php

$hora1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '12:04:32');
$hora2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '18:07:34');

echo $hora1->diff($hora2)->format('%H horas %i minutos e %s segundos');
```

Comment: +1 sempre é preferível orientação a objeto, por conta da reutilização :)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o objeto `DateTime()`:

```
<?php

$string1 = "12:04:32";
$string2 = "18:07:34";
list($h1,$m1,$s1) = explode(':',$string1);
list($h2,$m2,$s2) = explode(':',$string2);

$dateTimeOne = new DateTime();
$dateTimeOne->setTime($h1, $m1, $s1);

$dateTimeTwo = new DateTime();
$dateTimeTwo->setTime($h2, $m2, $s2);

$interval = $dateTimeOne->diff($dateTimeTwo);
echo $interval->format('%H horas %i minutos e %s segundos');
```

Comment: +1 Apesar de não ter gostado muito do `explode`, concordo que com a utilização do `setTime` torna a coisa toda mais interessante. E diferencia também das outras respostas, dando mais possibilidades de execução :)

Comment: Se não quiser usar explode, [pode fazer algo assim](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e49834a4817511593454d2f02a4050174424f72)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode converter as horas e minutos pra segundos pra ficar mais fácil de calcular a diferença.

```
$horaA = "01:30:00"; // HORA INICIAL
$horaB = "20:23:12"; // HORA FINAL

// Função de calculo. Se tiver mais de uma hora para calcular
// torne-a uma variável e adicione um parâmetro na função

function calculaTempo($hora_inicial, $hora_final){
    $i = 1;           // Para facilitar a lógica
    $tempo_total;

    $tempos = array($hora_final, $hora_inicial);

    foreach($tempos as $tempo) {
        $segundos = 0;

        // Cria uma lista com os valores de hora, minuto e segundo
        list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $tempo);

        // Passagem dos valores para segundos
        $segundos += $h * 3600;
        $segundos += $m * 60;
        $segundos += $s;

        $tempo_total[$i] = $segundos;

        $i++;
    }

    // Calculo da diferença do tempo em segundos
                // $horaA           $horaB          $horaC...
    $segundos = $tempo_total[1] - $tempo_total[2];

    // Valor das horas      
    $horas = floor($segundos / 3600);
    $segundos -= $horas * 3600;

    // Valor dos minutos
    $minutos = str_pad((floor($segundos / 60)), 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $segundos -= $minutos * 60;

    // Valor dos segundos
    $segundos = str_pad($segundos, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    // RESULTADO
    return "$horas:$minutos:$segundos";
}

$horario=calculaTempo($horaA, $horaB);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$timeString = date('H:i:s',strtotime($time))
```

Answer (score -5):

Usando

```
strtotome($string_da_dora)
```