# Temporizador de Data

Tags: php, html

Bom é o seguinte eu tenho uma determinada data e uma determinada hora.

Eu queria fazer com que o php me mostrasse quantos dias, horas, minutos e segundos faltam para essa determinada data e essa determinada hora.

Ou seja, eu tenho uma data e uma hora numa variável e quero que um echo em php me mostre quanto tempo falta para chegar a essa data.

Não precisa de ser em tempo real!

Quero que a data final tenha hora minuto e segundo.

Basta entrar no site e aparecer quanto tempo falta, não é preciso decrescer nem nada!

Espero que tenha sido entendido.
Obrigado.

Comment: Alterando em tempo real? Com php não acho que seja possivel, talvez com javascript.

Comment: Não é preciso ser em tempo real, basta entrar no site e dizer-me apenas quanto tempo falta para aquela data/hora/minuto/segundo.

Comment: Ah sim, tem como adicionar isso na pergunta? só pra ficar claro quando alguém for responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o exemplo desta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58/3635), mas com horas minutos e segundos:

```
$termina = new \DateTime('2017-12-11 11:14:15');
$hoje    = new \DateTime();

$intervalo = $hoje->diff($termina);

echo "Intervalo é de {$intervalo->y} anos, {$intervalo->m} meses e {$intervalo->d} dias, {$intervalo->h} horas, {$intervalo->i} minutos, {$intervalo->s} segundos";
```

Se quiser adicionar milesegundos faça assim:

```
2017-12-11 11:14:15.638276
```

O `638276` é o valor de milesegundo e não pode ser separado do `.`

**Documentação:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php
- `$intervalo->y` retorna ano
- `$intervalo->m` retorna mês
- `$intervalo->d` retorna dia
- `$intervalo->h` retorna hora
- `$intervalo->i` retorna minutos
- `$intervalo->s` retorna segundos

---

Para adicionar casas decimais pode usar o `str_pad` ou `sprintf`, como nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/51828/3635 (com o exemplo do `sprintf` indicado pelo colega @WallaceMaxters), então deve ficar:

```
$termina = new \DateTime('2050-12-11 11:14:15');
$hoje    = new \DateTime();

$intervalo = $hoje->diff($termina);

printf('%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', $intervalo->y, $intervalo->m, $intervalo->d, $intervalo->h, $intervalo->i, $intervalo->s);
```

Um exemplo online: https://ideone.com/DkK2WS

Comment: Mas por exemplo quero que $termina tenho uma hora especifica com minutos e segundos. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: @Gonçalo vou editar

Comment: Certo, obrigado.

Comment: @Gonçalo editado. Bastava ter lido a documentação que passei, mas ok é bom sempre ter um exemplo pratico também ;)

Comment: Já agora existe algum parametro que indica as milesimas de segundo também?

Comment: @Gonçalo sim, tá na documentação... Eita preguiça hein... (brincadeira :) ) vou editar

Comment: E no intervalo, ms significa milisegundos ou no intervalo não tem?

Comment: @Gonçalo você quer fazer leitura para os humanos ou para um computador? milesegundos geralmente não é leitura humana e sim para precisão de computadores. Se quer precisão então não use a classe, use valores primitivos como int, float, etc.

Comment: Eu queria fazer por este método mesmo, é para humanos, mas diga-me uma coisa não tem nenhum parametro de 2 casas ao lado do segundo? Se não tiver não tem problema, fica assim mesmo.

Comment: @Gonçalo explica melhor, tá confuso, que "casas"?

Comment: Refiro-me se existe algum parametro, que mostra 2 casas decimais ao lado do segundo.

Comment: @Gonçalo semelhante a isto `$intervalo->s` ? Mas para milesegundos?

Comment: Isso mesmo é mesmo isso!

Comment: @Gonçalo olhei a documentação e parece que não tem, como eu disse o milesegundos/microsegundos são usados para precisão e dificilmente isto vai interessar para humanos e por este motivo parece que não existe. Mas se encontrar algo depois eu edito.

Comment: Certo, obrigado assim mesmo já dá!

Comment: @Gonçalo sei que faz muito tempo e com certeza vc já resolveu isto, mas só pra avisar na época eu nem tinha me dado conta do str_pad e do sprintf ou printf, então adicionei isto a resposta, assim pode ter os decimais nas horas e dias ;)