# Sistema de tempo restante

Tags: php, data

Tenho um gerador de data e nele eu marco o dia que ira acontecer certo evento. Como visto na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse sistema retorna um valor em time(). Eu preciso de um código que diga o tempo restante, por exemplo, agora é: 9/3/2016 - 19:26 e o evento foi marcado para - 9/3/2016 - 21:00.

Eu quero que o código retorne o tempo restante. Por exemplo: faltam 2 dias, 1 hora e 10 minutos.

Aqui vão algumas datas para auxiliar na hora de fazer:

**23/03/2016 06:00 - time() - 1458723600**

**15/03/2016 09:00 - time() - 1458043200**

Tentei adaptar o código em um que já tenho, mas não deu certo.

Tenho esse código que faz o contrario do que quero, ele mostra o tempo que passou.

```
function tempo($time){
        $diff = time() - $time;
        $seconds = $diff;
        $minutes = round($diff / 60);
        $hours = round($diff / 3600);
        $days = round($diff / 86400);
        $weeks = round($diff / 604800);
        $months = round($diff / 2419200);
        $years = round($diff / 29030400);
        if($seconds < 10) return "Agora mesmo";
        if($seconds < 60) return "$seconds segundos";
        else if($minutes < 60) return $minutes==1 ?'1 minuto':$minutes.' minutos';
        else if($hours < 24) return $hours==1 ?'1 hora':$hours.' horas';
        else if($days < 7) return $days==1 ?'1 dia':$days.' dias';
        else if($weeks < 4) return $weeks==1 ?'1 semana':$weeks.' semanas';
        else if($months < 12) return $months == 1 ?'1 mes':$months.' meses';
        else return $years == 1 ? '1 ano':$years.' anos';
    }
```

Ele retorna valores do tipo: há 1 hora atrás, há 10 minutos, Agora mesmo, etc...

Comment: O que você já tentou? Quer que façamos o programa para você? Mostre um pouco de esforço e demonstre o que já tentou fazer, assim, as pessoas terão mais empatia para te ajudar. ;)

Comment: Tentei subtrai o tempo real com o tempo do evento e tentar ver o resultado mais não deu certo

Comment: Tentei adaptar um sistema que conta o tempo que passou mais não funcionou olhe o código que conta o tempo que passou:
http://prntscr.com/adalix Nesse caso ele retorna: há 10 minutos, há 1 hora etc...

Comment: Leandro clique em [edit] e adicione o código na pergunta, e deixe ela mais objetiva, da forma como está, parece que você espera que alguem faça tudo para você.

Comment: Editei acredito que deixei um pouco mais claro a base do código

Comment: Pode melhorar, tente focar apenas no seguinte: o que eu já tenho pronto? O que meu código precisa fazer? Como ele precisa fazer?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36775/discussion-between-leandro-ferreira-and-diego-f).

Comment: Existe uma função chamada diff na classe `DateTime`, veja um exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113086/3635

Answer (score 2):

Troca:

```
$diff = time() - $time;
```

Por

```
$diff = $time - time();
```