# Como calcular tempo em dias (Count-up) acumulativo em php?

Tags: php, contador

Galera, tudo bem? Sou novo aqui no fórum.

Procurei por todos os cantos e não consegui encontrar uma solução para o que eu preciso.

O conceito é simples:

O que eu preciso desenvolver basicamente é um contador de dias acumulativos que não possui uma data final definida, então eu determino uma data de início(hoje por exemplo, 18/07/18) e ele mostra em dias/horas/minutos/segundos quando tempo se passou desde aquela data...

Ex: Se passaram 41dias:09horas:03minutos:06segundos do dia 18/07/18

É importante que essa data seja fixa, de forma que ao recarregar a página, o contador não "resete" ou começe tudo denovo e que qualquer pessoa ao acessar a página veja o mesmo número/horário.

Os demais posts que encontrei traçam a diferença entre duas datas definidas, eu desejo definir somente a primeira data (início), **não há uma segunda data ainda**, ele precisa acumular o tempo infinitamente e dar um **echo/display** na tela

[image: Countup]

Existe um site que faz exatamente o que eu preciso, mas o problema é que eles não liberam o código do contador, apenas deixam você embeddar uma solução pronta.
segue link: https://www.tickcounter.com/countup

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer isso manualmente de forma que eu possa customizar 100% do código dele (adicionar HTML,CSS etc..) depois e colocar em meu site.

Desde já muito obrigado.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: você quer exibir esse resultado apenas ao carregar a página ou quer que ele vá atualizando? Por que daí é uma questão muito mais de javascript do que php

Comment: Segue um exemplo com casas decimais para dias horas e minutos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/113086/3635

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu preciso:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113082/temporizador-de-data/113086#113086

Você acertou em cheio! Porém eu preciso que ele vá atualizando em tempo real na tela (desculpe eu não sei nada de javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, acho que o código abaixo faz o que tu precisa.

```
$dtStart = new DateTime("2018-07-20"); 
$dtEnd   = new DateTime("2018-07-25 10:45:44"); 
$dtDiff = $dtStart->diff($dtEnd);
print $dtDiff->format("%d:%H:%I:%S");
```

Comment: Na verdade não, nesse código que você mostra você está definindo uma data final em $dtEnd.

Eu preciso que o contador acumule o tempo sem uma previsão de final, sabe?

Comment: Olá. Tente $dtEnd = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); Deste modo vai pegar a data atual do server. Se a versão do PHP foi acima da 5.2.0, pode ser assim $dtEnd = new DateTime();

Comment: Deu certo! obrigado.