# Subtração de horas em php

Tags: php

Quando faço a subtração dos horários o resultado é "0" quero que fique no formato de horário, exemplo: 19:38:20 - 19:37:00  = 00:01:20.

Obs: Os valores "tempo" do banco de dados que estou atribuindo a "$tempo1" e "$tempo2", estão no formato varchar. já testei ambos e estão no formato correto, mas ao subtrair não fica no formato de horário como dito antes...

código:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php

include "../../conexao.php";

// primeira parte 1

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tempo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$id = $row["id"];
$tempo1 = $row["tempo"];



$sql = "DELETE FROM tempo WHERE id='$id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
} else {
echo "Erro ao tentar deletar: " . $conn->error;
}

echo "$tempo1 <br>";



// segunda parte 2.2

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tempo2";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$id = $row["id"];
$corrida = $row["corrida"];
$nome1 = $row["nome"];
$numero = $row["numero"];
$tempo2 = $row["tempo"];

echo "$tempo2 <br>"; 


$sql = "DELETE FROM tempo2 WHERE id='$id'";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
} else {
echo "Erro ao tentar deletar: " . $conn->error;
}

$tempo = $tempo2 - $tempo1;
echo "$tempo <br>";

}

}
```

Comment: PHP não tem tipo nativo para datas e horas, então não faz muito sentido o seu `$tempo = $tempo2 - $tempo1`. Precisa converter para algum formato adequado antes de fazer a operação. Sugeriria você [edit] a pergunta acrescentando o tipo de variável que está sendo retornado em $tempo1 e 2, para que fique mais fácil de indicarmos um caminho mais adequado para a solução.

Comment: @Bacco não conheço outras linguagem com um tipo nativo para hora, mas no PHP temos a classe [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) para fazer tudo isso ai.

Comment: @gmsantos geralmente prefiro usar funções simples pra caso deste tipo, acho muito enrolada desnecessariamente a implementação do DateTime (uma das coisas que eu costumo fazer pra otimizar PHP inclusive é remover toda e qualquer ocorrência de DateTime que possa ser feita com funções nativas de tempo). Enquanto a DateTime está instanciando o objeto, a minha linha "avulsa" já retornou. Só de curiosidade, Clipper e Harbour tem tipo data nativo. Harbour tem timestamp nativo também. Você pode escrever isto em Harbour: `d = 0d20160425`, por exemplo. Se der um `print d + 6` vai obter `01/05/2016`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Voce pode usar a classe DateTime() para descobrir a diferenca entre duas datas.

```
/**
 * @param $dateStart - Data inicial
 * @param $dateEnd - Data final
 * @param $format  - Formato esperado de saida
 */
function dateDiff( $dateStart, $dateEnd, $format = '%a' ) {

    $d1     =   new DateTime( $dateStart );

    $d2     =   new DateTime( $dateEnd );

    //Calcula a diferença entre as datas
    $diff   =   $d1->diff($d2, true);   

    //Formata no padrão esperado e retorna
    return $diff->format( $format );

}
```

Os tipos de saida disponiveis sao: %Y Anos, %m Meses, %d Dias, %H Horas, %i Minutos, %s Segundos.
Para o seu caso, voce vai passar no ultimo parametro a seguinte string: '%H:%i:%s'

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in C:\Users\kaio gabriel\Desktop\finderserver\root\finder cronometragem\cronometro\calc\bd_resultado.php on line 55.               sabe me dizer a causa?

Comment: remova o `public` da declaracao do metodo. Vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: sete como melhor resposta por favor

Comment: @VanPersie Veja o [tour] você escolhe a resposta que melhor convier para você, não precisa escolher a que pediram.

Comment: @Duque n~]ao é legal ficar pedindo para aceitar a sua resposta. Se é para instruir o novo usuário, que seja imparcial dando a chance de todos serem aceitos.

Comment: @bigown, ele já tinha aceitado a minha resposta, mas ele não havia setado como melhor resposta. Tem uma galera que esquece disso.

Answer (score 15):

Nota: não lembrei dessa aqui e acabei respondendo uma duplicata com uma solução até mais elegante que a daqui (e obviamente sem usar DateTime, o que é mais importante).

Para quem seinteressar, segue link:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/149561/70

---

No caso, como se tratam de *strings*, uma linha de PHP com funções corriqueiras resolve:

```
$tempo = gmdate('H:i:s', strtotime( $tempo1 ) - strtotime( $tempo2 ) );
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/HoNekg)**.

A função `strtotime()` neste contexto vai transformar o tempo em numérico (em segundos), permitindo operações matemáticas convencionais.

Em seguida, a função `gmdate` converte em *string* novamente, no formato que você colocou na pergunta.

De curiosidade, se usar só essa parte:

```
strtotime( $tempo1 ) - strtotime( $tempo2 )
```

o resultado será 80, que é o número de segundos entre os tempos do seu exemplo.

Como a base de tempo do `strtotime()` é a *unix epoch*, você pode fazer isto para converter um horário para segundos "puros" (sem a parte da data):

```
strtotime( '1970-01-01 '.$horario );
```

Conforme comentário em outra duplicata do OP, segue uma alternativa para usar valores invertidos:

```
$tempo = gmdate('H:i:s', abs( strtotime( $tempo1 ) - strtotime( $tempo2 ) ) )
```

Na verdade é um exemplo que eu não imaginei que fosse necessário, pois é coisa extremamente básica, mas aí está.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/TsPN57)**.

Answer (score 7):

Você também pode utilizar uma biblioteca chamada [WallaceMaxters\Timer](https://packagist.org/packages/wallacemaxters/timer) para fazer isso:

```
use WallaceMaxters\Timer\Time;

$t1 = Time::createFromFormat(Time::DEFAULT_FORMAT, $tempo1);

$t2 = Time::createFromFormat(Time::DEFAULT_FORMAT, $tempo2);

$tempo = $t1->diff($t2)->format(Time::DEFAULT_FORMAT);
```

No código-fonte dessa biblioteca, podemos ver como é feita a comparação dos valores:

```
public function diff(Time $time, $absolute = true)
{
    $diff = $this->getSeconds() - $time->getSeconds();
    return new self(0, 0, $absolute ? abs($diff) : $diff);
}
```

Eu criei essa biblioteca para poder trabalhar com tempo em PHP, principalmente as que ultrapassam 24 horas.

Importante leitura:

[Como obter o formato em horas quando esta ultrapassa 24?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51821/como-obter-o-formato-em-horas-quando-esta-ultrapassa-24)

Answer (score 1):

Em uma forma bem simples, pode-se fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php
$dteini   = "2018/08/01 12:00:00";
$dtefim   = "2018/08/03 12:59:19";
$dteDiff  = strtotime($dtefim) - strtotime($dteini);
$dte      = new datetime(date('H:i:s'));
$dte      = $dteDiff;
print "Total " . $dte . "<br>";
$total    = $dte;
$horas    = floor($total / 3600);
$minutos  = floor(($total - ($horas * 3600)) / 60);
$segundos = floor($total % 60);
$horas    = str_pad($horas, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$minutos  = str_pad($minutos, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$segundos = str_pad($segundos, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $horas . ":" . $minutos . ":" . $segundos;
?>
```

Resultado:

> ```
> Total 176359
> 48:59:19
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Quem sabe ajudo!

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

// Data e hora atual
$datetime1 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

// Converter $datetime1 para o formato Unix timestamp
$timestamp = strtotime($datetime1);

// Tempo a ser subtraido - 01:30 horas
$horas = 1;      // cada hora corresponde a 3600 segundos
$minutos = 30;   // cada minuto corresponde a 60 segundos
$segundos = 0;

// Transforma o tempo a ser subtraido em segundos
$tempo = ($horas * 3600) + ($minutos * 60) + $segundos;

// Subtrair $tempo de $datetime1
$novaDataHora= $timestamp - $tempo;

// Data e hora apos a subtracao
$datetime2 = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $novaDataHora);

// Mostra os resultados
echo $datetime1 . '<br>';
echo $datetime2 . '<br>';

?>
```