# por que não está retornando a diferença de tempo?

Tags: php

Fiz uma mesma pergunta, mas essa quero saber onde está o erro, pois não retorna a diferença de tempo.

obs: quero que mostre a diferença de horário. exemplo: 7:50:10 - 7:50:00 = 00:00:10, mas não foi esse o resultado. Não está retornando nada.

código:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
include "../../conexao.php";
// primeira parte 1
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tempo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $tempo1 = $row["tempo"];
    echo "$tempo1 <br>";
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tempo WHERE id='$id'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
        echo "Erro ao tentar deletar: " . $conn->error;
    }
    // segunda parte 2.2
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tempo2";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id1 = $row["id"];
        $corrida = $row["corrida"];
        $nome1 = $row["nome"];
        $numero = $row["numero"];
        $tempo2 = $row["tempo"];
        echo "$tempo2 <br>"; 
        $sql = "DELETE FROM tempo2 WHERE id='$id1'";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        } else {
            echo "Erro ao tentar deletar: " . $conn->error;
        }
        function dateDiff( $tempo1, $tempo2, $format = '%H:%i:%s' ) {
            $d1     =   new DateTime( $tempo1 );
            $d2     =   new DateTime( $tempo2 );
            //Calcula a diferença entre as datas
            $diff   =   $d1->diff($d2, true);   
            //Formata no padrão esperado e retorna
            return $diff->format( $format );
        }
    }
}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ola, pode organizar o seu codigo por favor. (Sugiro que retire o codigo comentado para facilitar a leitura)

Comment: Você mesmo disse já ter feito essa pergunta, poderia ter questionado na outra. Evite criar duplicatas.

Comment: Quando opta-se pelo código mais simples é mais fácil acertar ou encontrar o erro. Na pergunta original tinha a solução simples, mas optou pela complicada. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125086/101

Comment: Se você está falando disto  "$tempo = date('H:i:s', strtotime( $tempo1 ) - strtotime( $tempo2 ) );"  isso apenas subtrai o horário, mas não mostra a diferença de tempo exemplo:  8:50:10 - 8:50:00 = 23:59:50. exemplo de como eu quero:  8:50:10 - 8:50:00 = 00:00:10

Comment: @VanPersie acho que  você não viu a demonstração, que mostra exatamente o que você pediu na pergunta, tem link lá mostrando funcionando. Claramente você está invertendo os valores no seu teste, mas se tivesse comentado, eu simplesmente complementaria com um `abs( )` pra funcionar independente da ordem. O fato é que basta você clicar no link do IDEONE para ver o código funcionando, mas se quiser que valores invertidos funcionem também, basta um `$tempo = date('H:i:s', abs( strtotime( $tempo1 ) - strtotime( $tempo2 ) ) )`

Answer (score 1):

```
    function dateDiff( $tempo1, $tempo2, $format = '%H:%i:%s' ) {
        $d1     =   new DateTime( $tempo1 );
        $d2     =   new DateTime( $tempo2 );
        //Calcula a diferença entre as datas
        $diff   =   $d1->diff($d2, true);   
        //Formata no padrão esperado e retorna
        return $diff->format( $format );
    }
```

Coloque fora do while, porque é apenas uma função e voce não precisa de varias funções mas sim precisa usar/invocar varias vezes.

Após colocar a função fora do while (e antes do while) tem de chamar/invocar a função onde pretende que seja usada.

No seu exemplo ficará.:

```
function dateDiff( $tempo1, $tempo2, $format = '%H:%i:%s' ) {
    $d1     =   new DateTime( $tempo1 );
    $d2     =   new DateTime( $tempo2 );
    //Calcula a diferença entre as datas
    $diff   =   $d1->diff($d2, true);   
    //Formata no padrão esperado e retorna
    return $diff->format( $format );
}

// primeira parte 1
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tempo";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $tempo1 = $row["tempo"];
    echo "$tempo1 <br>";
    $sql = "DELETE FROM tempo WHERE id='$id'";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
        echo "Erro ao tentar deletar: " . $conn->error;
    }
    // segunda parte 2.2
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tempo2";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id1 = $row["id"];
        $corrida = $row["corrida"];
        $nome1 = $row["nome"];
        $numero = $row["numero"];
        $tempo2 = $row["tempo"];
        echo "$tempo2 <br>"; 
        $sql = "DELETE FROM tempo2 WHERE id='$id1'";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        } else {
            echo "Erro ao tentar deletar: " . $conn->error;
        }
        echo dateDiff($tempo1, $tempo2, $format = '%H:%i:%s').'<br>';
    }
}
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Coloquei um 'br' para a informação ser separada por linha.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone...        sabe me dizer a causa do erro?

Comment: Para o que percebi não tem configurado o timezone no php.ini.veja se ajuda.: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php