# Calcular intervalo de tempo em horas e minutos considerando dias diferentes

Tags: php, time

Por enquanto eu tenho esse código que está calculando o intervalo entre as horas. Eu quero incrementar o cálculo com minutos, e quero fazer algumas alterações na lógica, por exemplo quando eu coloco a hora de entrada como 23 horas e hora de saida como 12 horas do outro dia, ele me retorna 11 horas, sendo que deve retornar 13.

```
<?php 
$hi = 23;
$hf = 12;
$total = -1;

$maior = calculaMaior($hi,$hf);
$menor = calculaMenor($hi,$hf);

for($i = $maior ; $i >= $menor ; $i--){
    $total++;
    echo"<br>$total<br>";//aqui ele irá mostrar todos os números só pra garantir
}
$aux = $maior + $total;
$total  = $aux - $total;
echo "<br>**************$total*************";

function calculaMaior($n1, $n2){
    if($n1 > $n2){
        return $n1;
    }else if($n1 < $n2){
        return $n2;
    }
}
function calculaMenor($n1, $n2){
    if($n1 > $n2){
        return $n2;
    }else if($n1 < $n2){
        return $n1;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Para prazos de 24 horas ou mais, convém usar data:

É necessário que se especifique a data nestes casos, para desambiguação.

O PHP já tem funções de data muito eficientes para se usar em cálculos matemáticos, evitando o uso das classes de data que são **complexas internamente** e **ineficientes**, principalmente para coisas pontuais.

Para converter uma data em *timestamp* (que é tipo numérico) temos a:

```
gmmktime( hora, minuto, segundo, mes, dia, ano )
```

**Cuidado**, como é PHP, é claro que a ordem dos parâmetros é sem sentido. Note que o mês vem antes do dia.

Veja como usar:

```
<?php
 
    $entrada = gmmktime(  23, 30, 00, 05, 25, 2010 );
    $saida   = gmmktime(  11, 15, 00, 05, 26, 2010 );
 
    echo ( $saida - $entrada ) / 3600;
```

Note que nem precisou criar uma função, é matemática pura.

Para formatar a saída, é muito simples:

```
<?php
 
    $entrada = gmmktime(  23, 30, 00, 05, 25, 2010 );
    $saida   = gmmktime(  11, 15, 00, 05, 26, 2010 );
    $diferenca = abs( $saida - $entrada );
    
    printf( '%d:%d', $diferenca/3600, $diferenca/60%60 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6e80f51ae881a1b462b1b23ee8141097d6a3c1a6)**.

- O `abs( )` serve para ignorar a ordem das datas, tornando a diferença sempre positiva. Se a saída for sempre maior, pode simplificar com `$diferenca = $saida - $entrada;`.
- a divisão é para transformar os tempos em horas e minutos, pois os *timestamps* são sempre expressos em segundos.

Se preferir passar as datas por *string* é muito parecido:

```
<?php
 
    $entrada = strtotime( '2010-05-25 23:30' );
    $saida   = strtotime( '2010-05-26 11:15' );
    $diferenca = $saida - $entrada;
    
    printf( '%d:%d', $diferenca/3600, $diferenca/60%60 );
```

Veja funcionando no **[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d8c4d92fc4b3f094e08563dedf544d10e7d7d3c)**.

Lembrando que interpretar *strings* normalmente é menos performático do que usar números separados. Não é tão ruim quanto instanciar um DateTime, mas já é uma etapa a mais.

### Para prazos de menos de 24 horas pode optar até por matemática básica:

Você não especificou como vai entrar com os minutos, mas de qualquer forma, tou dando exemplos variados para dar opções:

```
<?php
    $entrada = '23:15';
    $saida   = '11:30';

    print_r( intervalo( $entrada, $saida ) );

    function intervalo( $entrada, $saida ) {
       $entrada = explode( ':', $entrada );
       $saida   = explode( ':', $saida );
       $minutos = ( $saida[0] - $entrada[0] ) * 60 + $saida[1] - $entrada[1];
       if( $minutos < 0 ) $minutos += 24 * 60;
       return sprintf( '%d:%d', $minutos / 60, $minutos % 60 );
    }
```

Veja funcionando no **[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/49e93fc9bfde73270fa8071c633945d1900460d3)**.

Com campos separados:

```
<?php
    $entradaH = 23;
    $entradaM = 15;
    $saidaH   = 11;
    $saidaM   = 30;

    print_r( intervalo( $entradaH, $entradaM, $saidaH, $saidaM ) );

    function intervalo( $entradaH, $entradaM, $saidaH, $saidaM ) {
       $minutos = ( $saidaH - $entradaH ) * 60 + $saidaM - $entradaM;
       if( $minutos < 0 ) $minutos += 24 * 60;
       return sprintf( '%d:%d', $minutos / 60, $minutos % 60 );
    }
```

Veja funcionando no **[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce07445b04778269a83542fe902cfa3808984169)**.

Com Array:

```
<?php
    $entrada = array( 'h'=>23, 'm'=>15 );
    $saida   = array( 'h'=>11, 'm'=>30 );

    print_r( intervalo( $entrada, $saida ) );

    function intervalo( $entrada, $saida ) {
       $minutos = ( $saida['h'] - $entrada['h'] ) * 60 + $saida['m'] - $entrada['m'];
       if( $minutos < 0 ) $minutos += 24 * 60;
       return array( 'h'=>(int)( $minutos / 60), 'm'=>( $minutos % 60 ) );
    }
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/oe8R2g)**.

Se quiser simplificar, especificando a hora em fracionais, em vez de 11:30 usar 11.5   (onze e meio), em vez de 23:15 usar 23.25  (vinte e três e um quarto):

```
<?php
    $entrada = 23.25;
    $saida   = 11.50;

    print_r( intervalo( $entrada, $saida ) );

    function intervalo( $entrada, $saida ) {
       $minutos = (int)($entrada * 60 - $saida * 60 );
       if( $minutos < 0 ) $minutos += 24 * 60;
       return $minutos / 60;
    }
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/IDEzK1)**.

Desta forma você delega a formatação em uma função separada para exibir em minutos e segundos na tela, evitando conversões desnecessárias.

- Ambas verificam se a hora de saída é menor, e já fazem o ajuste para o dia seguinte.
- Isto faz sentido para prazos de menos de 24 horas. Mais que isso, precisa especificar data.

Comment: No caso, eu gostaria de pegar a hora e o minuto em inputs diferentes, como eu faria pra eu juntar os dois afim de fazer os cálculos?

Comment: Acrescentei na resposta uma opção que aceita campos separados. Demonstração http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce07445b04778269a83542fe902cfa3808984169

Comment: okay, vou testar

Comment: Como eu poderia fazer se eu quiser usar os campos como arrays, caso eu tivesse mais de um "cliente" ?

Comment: @MickaelSouza tem várias maneiras, mas se fizer um loop chamando a função "intervalo", já resolve.

Comment: Ok, vou implementar dessa forma

Answer (score 2):

Cálculo de tempo depende da data.

A rotina que criaste não considera a data, por isso retorna o valor literal 11.

Veja aqui uma simulação do que você está fazendo, porém usando a classe DateTime, nativa do PHP:

```
// Create two new DateTime-objects...
$date1 = new DateTime('2016-08-28T23:00:00'); // pode definir sem a letra T, assim "2016-08-28 23:00:00". O importante é que tenha o formato ISO 8601
$date2 = new DateTime('2016-08-28T12:00:00');


// The diff-methods returns a new DateInterval-object...
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);

// Call the format method on the DateInterval-object
echo $diff->format('%a Day and %h hours');
```

Pelo que entendi da pergunta, o hário 12:00 seria do dia seguinte, portanto é uma data no dia seguinte:

```
// Create two new DateTime-objects...
$date1 = new DateTime('2016-08-28T23:00:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2016-08-29T12:00:00');


// The diff-methods returns a new DateInterval-object...
$diff = $date2->diff($date1);

// Call the format method on the DateInterval-object
echo $diff->format('%a Day and %h hours');
```

O formato acima são exemplos didáticos. Para algo mais objetivo, teste isso:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2016-08-28T23:00:00');
$date2 = new DateTime('2016-08-29T12:00:00');

$diff = $date2->diff($date1);

$hours = $diff->h;
$hours = $hours + ($diff->days*24);

echo $hours;
```

Para mais detalhes:

- [DateTime-Class](http://php.net/manual/class.datetime.php)
- [DateTimeZone-Class](http://php.net/manual/class.datetimezone.php)
- [DateInterval-Class](http://php.net/manual/class.dateinterval.php)
- [DatePeriod-Class](http://php.net/manual/class.dateperiod.php)

Alternativamente pode chegar ao mesmo resultado usando funções como strtotime(), gmmktime(), dentre outras, mas não faz diferença na performance. Ambos executam na mesma quantidade de tempo. Uma pequena diferença é que o consumo de memória final apresenta uma diferença de 1.3kb com DateTime, no entanto, no pico de uso de memória a diferença é de 400 bytes a mais para library DateTime.

Note que esse tempo pode variar de acordo com o ambiente e foi feito sem otimização alguma. O uso de um opcache tornaria a diferença nula, por exemplo.

A diferença nesse custo seria relevante caso executasse num processo massivo de longa duração e sem nenhuma otimização executando tudo com redudâncias feito um louco.

Por fim, tudo tem um custo. Pode escolher montar tudo isso juntando um quebra cabeças de funções antigas com parâmetros "sem um padrão amigável e lógico" e ficar reclamando que o PHP é ruim (coisa de mimizento), ou usar uma library que foi criada para corrigir essa bagunça e trazer mais funcionalidades.

Particularmente, até um tempo atrás eu preferia evitar libraries como DateTime, mas decidi dar o braço a torcer e usar esses recursos. Facilitam muito no desenvolvimento e manutenção, tal como na flexibilidade do sistema.