# Converter a diferença entre datas para string

Tags: php

Estou calculando no PHP a diferença entre duas `datetimes` (inicio,fim), vindas de um `POST`, preciso preencher um `campo(time)` no `format(H:i:s)` via `INSERT` no `MYSQL`.

Consigo o resultado da diferença, porém não consigo usa-lo pois ao realizar o `insert` recebo um erro dizendo que o campo diferença não esta convertido para `string`:

> Erro: "(Object of class DateInterval could not be converted to
>   string)".

Se for erro de `string` mesmo, como realizo a conversão? A alguma outra forma de fazer isso no `PHP`?

```
$inicio = new DateTime($data_inicio); 
$fim   = new DateTime($data_fim);

$duracao = $inicio->diff($fim);
$duracao = $duracao->format('%h:%i:%s');

$sql = "INSERT into horarios VALUES ('$duracao')";
```

Agradeço a parceria de sempre

<sub>*P.S.: Caso já tenha esta dúvida esclarecida em outro post me informem, mas dei uma pesquisada primeiro e estou me batendo um bocado.*</sub>

Comment: Veja se ajuda [Calcular intervalo de tempo em horas e minutos considerando dias diferentes](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/149539/70)

Comment: Dei uma olhada, não entendi muito bem... vou rever depois, gostaria de algo simples como o diff, caso não haja prefiro dai fazer via alguma biblioteca tipo moment do javascript e somente postar o valor já calculado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possibilidade, usando subtração simples e inteiros:

```
$date1 = strtotime( '10/04/2016 15:03' );
$date2 = strtotime( '10/04/2016 16:28' );

$duracao = date( 'H:i:s', abs( $date2 - $date1 ) );

// Aqui usa o valor como necessitar:
$sql = "INSERT INTO horarios VALUES ('$duracao')";
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/oH4gBu)**.

**Importante** notar que quando a data é separada por **traços**, o PHP já interpreta como `DD-MM-AAAA`, e com **barras** como `MM/DD/AAAA`. Se precisar, pode trocar assim:

```
strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', '11/04/2016 18:10'));
```

### Se precisar comparar a diferença de tempo com a data atual

Basta em vez de usar `strtotime( "$data $hora" );`, optar por uma destas funções

```
$date2 = mktime(); // Use essa se quiser hora local
$date2 = time();   // Ou essa se quiser UTC
```

Comment: Se precisar de aspas duplas, pode fazer `$sql = 'INSERT INTO horarios VALUES ("'.$duracao.'")';`

Comment: Simples e resolvido. não sabia ainda da existência do abs, há algum ponto negativo ou erro que possa ser gerado utilizando este método ? por exemplo se eu calcular uma duração entre meses.

Comment: @Cleverson o `abs` simplesmente retorna o valor absoluto (tira o "negativo" do número), não tem nenhum efeito colateral. Problemas de duração em intervalos muito grandes seriam causados pela aritmética de inteiros, mas isso afeta qualquer aplicação, independente da técnica usada.

Answer (score 2):

Hugo, certifique-se de que seu campo no banco de dados seja time ou alguma coisa do tipo, a partir da versão 5.6 do php é possível que os objetos time conversem diretamente com o banco de dados, por favor, caso sua tabela esteja em string o que não é recomendável, você deve explorar o objeto DateInterval formata-lo para string e adicionar ao banco, caso não consiga e se quiser, poderá também usar a biblioteca [Chronus](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos).

Comment: Bem interessante a biblioteca, com certeza irei começar a utiliza-la. Valew Sebastiao

Answer (score 0):

Use com a função date_diff:

```
$differenceFormat = "%H:%i:%s"

$datetime1 = date_create($data_inicio);
$datetime2 = date_create($data_fim);

$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

$sql = "INSERT into horarios VALUES ('$interval->format($differenceFormat);')";
```

Comment: Hugo, tentei aplicar mas ao realizar o insert gera um erro: "Undefined property: DateInterval::$format".