# Como verificar quanto tempo é que passou de uma certa hora e data

Tags: php

Bom é o seguinte, eu tenho duas variáveis.

```
$data = "27/12/2016";
$hora = "17:20";
```

Queria fazer um script em PHP que me indicasse quantos dias, horas e minutos é que se passou dessa tal data e hora.

Como poderei fazer?

Obrigado.

Comment: Tem essa aqui também, que faz exatamente o que vc descreveu: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156717/70

Comment: Eu já percebi a ideia no outro, como faço para o formado de data ficar: dia/mes/ano, em vez de mes/dia/ano ? Obrigado.

Comment: atualizei ambas para por um destaque maior na questão das barras, mas se tiver alguma duvida extra avise.