# No PHP utilizando datetime.format qual significado do %a

Tags: php, datetime

Gostaria de saber qual significado do `%a` utilizado em Data time no PHP, os outros achei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125086/subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-horas-em-php):

```
%Y Anos,
%m Meses,
%d Dias,
%H Horas,
%i Minutos,
%s Segundos
```

Seria o `a` na tabela do [manual do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)?

Comment: Sim, todos os símbolos disponíveis estão na página do manual que você linkou.

Answer (score 0):

A tabela completa está [nessa outra página da documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php#refsect1-datetime.format-parameters).

`%a` representa o período do dia com "am" ou "pm" e é útil ao exibir horas no formato de 12 horas com `%h`.