# Cálculo de horas com php

Tags: php, sql

Como calcular a horário que a pessoa entrou e o horário que a pessoa saiu menos o intervalo e exibir o total de horas que deu?

Por exemplo se um cara fez o seguinte horário: **07:30 12:00 13:30 17:00** teria que exibir: **8 horas trabalhadas**. Só que tenho que calcular de vários dias igual na imagem e somar todos os totais de horas de  que deu e exibir  o resultado.

Colunas no banco:

**marcacoes**
id(int)
dia(date) "data do horário"
tipo(char) E(entrada) ou S(saida)
hora(time) "são os horários"
colaborador_id(int)

Tenho a seguinte consulta sql:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT dia, GROUP_CONCAT(hora) FROM marcacoes WHERE colaborador_id = {$colaborador_id} AND dia between  '{$periodoInicial}' and  '{$periodoFinal}' GROUP BY dia ");
```

A exibição é feita através do código em php:

```
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){                
$tabela ='<tbody>'; 
$tabela .='<tr>';
$tabela .='<td>'.date("d-m-Y", strtotime($exibe['dia'])).'</td>'; 
$tabela .='<td>'.$exibe['GROUP_CONCAT(hora)'].'</a>'.'</td>';
$tabela .='</tr>';
$tabela .='</tbody>';   
echo $tabela;           
}
```

Retorna a seguinte tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado desejado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Essa marcação está como? Você tem uma coluna para cada registro?

Comment: Sim, tenho uma coluna para cada registro de marcação

Comment: Pode adicionar o nome das colunas na pergunta, para eu poder te ajudar na resposta?

Comment: Entendi! achei que sua tabela estava assim: `marcacoes:['id', 'data', 'entrada', 'saida_almoco', 'retorno_almoco', 'saida']`. Assim creio que ficaria mais fácil, mas não vamos conseguir contornar essa situação. Vou pensar numa resposta.

Comment: Acabei de editar..de uma olhada

Comment: Ah, você dá um `GROUP BY dia`. Essa informação é importante. Vou pensar aqui

Comment: Obrigado Wallace..

Comment: a propria sql ja traz os horarios separados fazendo um GROUP_CONCAT(hora) e dando um GROUP BY dia e consigo mostrar só passando: $exibe['GROUP_CONCAT(hora)']

Answer (score 1):

Percebi que você está utilizando um padrão de um registro na tabela para cada ação. Por isso precisou do `GROUP CONCAT`, que por usa vez retornará os dados seperados por `vírgula`.

Então, uma possível solução para calcular seria usando a função do MYSQL chamada `TIME_TO_SEC` para converter esse campo `TIME` e tornar ele em um `INTEGER`.

```
SELECT dia, TIME_TO_SEC(hora) FROM marcacoes
```

O resultada da query seria algo parecido com isso:

```
 dia        | hora
 2016-09-01 | 27000 (equivalente a 07:30)
 2016-09-01 | 43200 (equivalente a 12:30)
 2016-09-01 | 48600 (equivalente a 13:30)
 2016-09-01 | 63000 (equivalente a 17:30)
```

Com o GROUP CONCAT e GROUP BY  dia, ficaria assim:

```
 SELECT dia, GROUP_CONCAT(TIME_TO_SEC(hora)) as grupo_hora FROM marcacoes

 dia        | grupo_hora
 2016-09-01 | 27000,43200,48600,63000
```

Sendo assim, poderíamos fazer uma obra engenhosa para calcular a distância entre os horários.

```
  list($entrada, $almoco_entrada, $almoco_saida, $saida) = explode(',', $resultado['grupo_hora']);

  $diferenca_em_segundos = $saida - $entrada - ($almoco_saida - $almoco_entrada);
```

Agora temos um pequeno problema: A conversão de `$diferenca_em_segundos` para o formato de tempo.

Então você pode usar a função `gmdate`:

```
gmdate("H:i", $diferenca_em_segundos); // 08:00
```

O único problema do `gmdate` nesse caso, é que ele poderá retornar valores inesperados caso o valor dos segundos passe de uma soma de 24 horas.

Aí a solução seria essa nesse caso:

[Como obter o formato em horas quando esta ultrapassa 24?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51821/como-obter-o-formato-em-horas-quando-esta-ultrapassa-24)

Answer (score -4):

Olá

A partir da versão PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 o PHP conta com a classes DateTime que lida com tempo com diversas funcionalidades.
Especificamente na sua necessidade o DateTime::diff vai te ajudar
Dá uma olhada na documentação que será útil.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime($dataDoMysql1); // ex: 2016-08-01 06:00:00
$datetime2 = new DateTime($dataDoMysql2); // ex: 2016-08-03 10:00:00
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```