# Cálculo de arrays com formato de tempo pelo $_POST em PHP

Tags: php

Eu possuo um formulário dinâmico de onde vem o nome da interrupção, hora de início e hora de término.
Ele deve retornar as interrupções e os horários adicionados, porém, no campo total de horas perdidas, ele tem que subtrair o término pelo início e somar com outra interrupção caso tenha.
Exemplo abaixo:

[image: Exemplo]

O problema é que ele está mostrando no total, o primeiro cálculo, e a soma.
Código abaixo:

```
  $mostrar = 0;
  $somah = 0;
  $somam = 0;
  for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['interrupcao']); $i++) {

   $total = strtotime($_POST['terminoint'][$i]) - strtotime($_POST['inicioint'][$i]);
   $horas      = floor($total / 60 / 60);
   $minutos    = round(($total - ($horas * 60 * 60)) / 60);

   $somah += $horas;
   $somam += $minutos;

   $mostrar .= $somah.":".$somam;

   $html .="<tr>";
   $html .="<td>{$_POST['interrupcao'][$i]}</td>";
   $html .="<td>{$_POST['inicioint'][$i]}</td>";
   $html .="<td>{$_POST['terminoint'][$i]}</td>";
   $html .= "</tr>";
  }
```

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar um pouco: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51821/como-obter-o-formato-em-horas-quando-esta-ultrapassa-24/51826#51826

Comment: Eu também criei [uma biblioteca](https://github.com/wallacemaxters/timer) que me ajuda na hora que preciso calcular essas coisas :p

Comment: Obrigado, vou dar uma conferida nesta biblioteca =)

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver =/