# Remover uma hora com minutos ou não de uma data

Tags: php, datetime

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php

  //batidas do controle de ponto de um x colaborador
  $d1 = new DateTime('2021-08-06 12:00:00');
  $d2 = new DateTime('2021-08-06 15:00:00');
  $d3 = new DateTime('2021-08-06 15:30:00');
  $d4 = new DateTime('2021-08-06 17:00:00');
  $d5 = new DateTime('2021-08-06 17:30:00');
  $d6 = new DateTime('2021-08-06 21:00:00');

  $i1 = $d1->diff($d2);
  $i2 = $d2->diff($d3);

  $remover = new DateInterval("T1H");

  echo $i1->format('%H:%I') . "<br />";
  echo $i2->format('%H:%I') . "<br />";

  print_r($i1->sub($remover));
```

Aí da o seguinte erro:

> "FATAL ERROR Uncaught Exception: DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (T1H) in /var/www/html/index.php74(3) : eval()'d code:13 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/index.php74(3) : eval()'d code(13): DateInterval->__construct('T1H') #1 /var/www/html/index.php74(3): eval() #2 {main} thrown on line number 13"

Porém não sei o que esta errado? Gostaria de subtrair uma hora da variável `$i1` ou colocar como parâmetro na classe `DateInterval()` uma hora com segundos ou não dinamicamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), o construtor de `DateInterval` aceita strings no formato descrito pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

E segundo esta norma, durações **sempre** começam com a letra "P". Portanto, o intervalo de uma hora deve ser escrito como `PT1H`:

```php
$remover = new DateInterval("PT1H");
```

Porém, isso ainda não resolve o problema de subtrair um `DateInterval` de outro. O método `sub` só está disponível para `DateTime` (para subtrair uma duração de uma data).

Porém, `$i1` é uma duração (um `DateInterval`), pois ele é o resultado do `diff` (a diferença entre duas datas é uma duração - entenda melhor lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/401064/112052)). E para subtrair dois `DateInterval`'s você teria que fazer manualmente. Infelizmente não tem nada pronto, mas você pode se basear, por exemplo, [neste código aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30538079):

```php
// subtrai dois DateInterval's e retorna outro com o resultado
function subtractDateIntervals($intervalOne, $intervalTwo) {
    $keys = ["y", "m", "d", "h", "i", "s"];

    $intervalArrayOne = array_intersect_key((array)$intervalOne, array_flip($keys));
    $intervalArrayTwo = array_intersect_key((array)$intervalTwo, array_flip($keys));

    $result = array_map(function($v1, $v2){
        return abs($v1 - $v2);
    }, $intervalArrayOne, $intervalArrayTwo);

    return new DateInterval(vsprintf("P%dY%dM%dDT%dH%dM%dS", $result));
}

print_r(subtractDateIntervals($i1, $remover));
```